# How to check if there are folders in a path and open them in c#

Tags: c#, file

I have been trying to make a console app that asks you for the path and extension and prints all the names of files that have the extension inputted in the path, but I want to make it so that if there are any more folders in the path then it will open the folder and search for a file with the extension inputted by the user.

Here is my code:

```
            Console.WriteLine("What is the path?");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is the extension?");
            string extension = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, $"*{extension}");        
            foreach(string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));   
            }
```

my code just looks for the file only in the path provided, but it doesn't look into a folder and search for a file

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for the overload with the parameter `searchOptions`? See [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) for a description. That would be `GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Comment: You don't "open" a folder for reading in Windows. I am assuming you want your program to recursively walk a directory and open any matching files?

Comment: Oh yes that would be it, thank you

Comment: @tanveer badar yes that was my intention

Comment: Use the overload @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica mentions then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method should accomplish what you want. You'll have to supply the folder and the extension as `"\folder\*.ext"` or similar as the parameter.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of files matching the wildcard.
        /// The directory specified in the wildcard and all its child directories are searched.
        /// If no directory part is specified, the current directory and its children are searched.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="wildcard">Wild card to match files (required).</param>
        /// <returns>A list of files matching the wildcard.</returns>
        public static List<string> getFilesMatchingWildcardRecursive(string wildcard)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(wildcard))
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException($"Required parameter {nameof(wildcard)} is null or empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(wildcard);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory)) { directory = "."; }
                string filepart = Path.GetFileName(wildcard);
                return new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(directory, filepart, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
            }
        }
```

Comment: An enumerable returning method should never return a null, if there are no elements to return, return an empty sequence, something like `new List<T>`, `Array.Empty<T>()` or `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.

Comment: Good point, Tanveer Badar. But here, not having a `wildcard` is actually more of an error condition. `Directory.GetFiles` will throw an exception if the `searchPattern` parameter is null; the documentation doesn't mention what happens if it is empty. I made an edit to make `wildcard` required and throw an exception if it's missing.